# Сортировка элементов в GridView

Tags: java, android, сортировка, коллекции

```
 //Пытаюсь сортировать по цветам в столбик,есть ли в GridView индексы как в 
 //массиве i ,j? Ничего в голову не приходит...

           GridView gvMain;Adapter adapter;
//Коллекция цветов:
            ArrayList<Colors> color =new ArrayList<Colors>();
//Коллекция с рандомными цветами:

        ArrayList<Colors> colors =new ArrayList<Colors>();
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
//Заполнение коллекции color:

            color.add(new Colors(Color.RED));
            color.add(new Colors(Color.YELLOW));
            color.add(new Colors(Color.GREEN));
            color.add(new Colors(Color.BLACK));
            color.add(new Colors(Color.BLUE));
        randomm();//
        gvMain = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gvMain);
//Создала свой класс адаптер:

        adapter = new Adapter(getApplicationContext(), colors);
        gvMain.setAdapter(adapter);
        GridView();//метод
     }

      public void randomm(){

        for (int i = 0; i <50 ; i++) {
            System.out.println();
            colors.add(randomItem(color));
        }
     }
       Random random;
//Рандомно выбирает индекс:

       public Colors randomItem(ArrayList mylist) {
        random = new Random();
        Colors randomInt = color.get(random.nextInt(color.size()));
        System.out.println(randomInt);
        return randomInt;
    }

     private void GridView() {
//задаю кол столбцов,без него 1 столбик выводит:

        gvMain.setNumColumns(5);
        gvMain.setColumnWidth(190);
        gvMain.setVerticalSpacing(4);
        gvMain.setHorizontalSpacing(4);
        gvMain.setStretchMode(GridView.NO_STRETCH);
     }
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.btn1:
                Collections.sort(colors);//Ошибка
            }

     @Override
     public int compareTo(@NonNull Colors o) {
        return 0;
       }
     }
```

// С Collections.sort(colors); показывает ошибку:

[image: ошибка]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так вопрос в том что вылезает ошибка?

Comment: @avp Да,пытаюсь сортировать ArrayList(colors) а затем обновить  адаптер.И еще вопрос такой...Вот например у меня 12 красных 9 желтых(всего 50) Можно ли сделать так чтоб  в 1 ом столбце GridView были только красные во 2 ом желтые и  т.д.....Я только знаю что grid View делит на столбцы с равным количеством элементов в столбце (setNumColumns())

Comment: там есть отличия когда sort с одним параметром и с двумя, думаю ошибка в этом, компилятор на знает как же сортировать. Вот статья https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16425127/how-to-use-collections-sort-in-java-specific-situation